# JSON array can't be converted into JSON object

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm working on json parsing project. The error is showing as json array cant be converted into json object. Here is the json view.

```
{
"State Name": [
    [
        {
            "state_name": "New South Wales (NSW)"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "state_name": "Western Australia (WA)"
        }
    ]
]
```

}

java code is:

```
try {
    JSONArray statesnames = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STATE_NAME);


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+statesnames.length(), 3000).show();


                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for(int i = 0; i < statesnames.length(); i++){


                        JSONObject c = statesnames.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Yes, a JSON array cannot be converted to JSON object. What is your question?

Comment: As you didn't show the code, its very hard to tell the error. Still I think you have declare JsonObject instead of JsonArray. Here is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to send both arrays in one response you could do that:

```
[                                         
   [{"state_name":"New South Wales (NSW)"}],
   [{"state_name":"Western Australia (WA)"}]
]
```

Take your JSONObject first as

```
JSONObject result= new JSONObject(json);
JSONArray arr= result.getJSONArray("State Name");
```

Whole `JSON` string is a `JSONArray`:

`getJSONArray(0)` contains `JSONObjects` with `state_name` as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
          JSONArray firstArry = arr.getJSONArray(i);

          for (int j = 0; j < firstArry.length(); j++) {
                 JSONObject secondarr= firstArry.getJSONObject(j);
                 System.out.println("state_name result: "+secondarr.getString("state_name"));
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
{

    "State Name":[   --> JSONArray
        [            --> JSONArray
            {        --> JSONObject
                "state_name":"New South Wales (NSW)"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "state_name":"Western Australia (WA)"
            }
        ]
    ]

}
```

**Example :**

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray statesnames = json.getJSONArray("State Name");

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < statesnames.length(); i1++) {
          JSONArray jsonarray = statesnames.getJSONArray(i1);

          for (int i2 = 0; i2 < jsonarray.length(); i2++) {
                 JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i2);
                 System.out.println("state_name : "+jsonobject.getString("state_name"));
          }
}
```